# Replace non alphanumeric characters to check palindrome using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, palindrome

```
function palindrome(str) {
  var strReverse=str.toLowerCase().replace(/\W+/g,'').split('').reverse().join('');
  if(strReverse===str)
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}
```

This program should check for the following palindromes:

```
palindrome("eye") should return true.

palindrome("race car") should return true.

palindrome("not a palindrome") should return false.

palindrome("A man, a plan, a canal. Panama") should return true.

palindrome("never odd or even") should return true.

palindrome("nope") should return false.

palindrome("almostomla") should return false.

palindrome("My age is 0, 0 si ega ym.") should return true.

palindrome("1 eye for of 1 eye.") should return false.

palindrome("0_0 (: /-\ :) 0-0") should return true.
```

But its not working for the multi string lines. I think its because of the `RegEx` but I cannot seem to find what is exactly wrong.

Comment: Try print both string and reversed string. This will help you to find issue.

Comment: Just use `if(strReverse===str.toLowerCase().replace(/\W+/g, ''))` condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this function

```
function palindrome(str) {
    str=str.toLowerCase().replace(/[^A-Za-z]+/g, '');
    var strReverse = str.split('').reverse().join('');
    if(strReverse===str)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

**Issue in your code** was that when you were comparing the `strReverse` with `str`, `strReverse` was formatted but `str` was not. Like you didn't remove special characters and spaces and numbers from str, you didn't made it `lowercase` etc.

[Check this fiddle for every test case](http://jsfiddle.net/voidSO/q1qo90d5/)

Comment: Thanks a lot..Its working now

Answer (score 2):

You're using `toLowerCase` when creating `strReverse`, and then comparing it with `str`. But `str` will still have upper-case characters in it. Additionally, you're leaving the non-alpha characters in `str`.

You also need to remove `_` for the last one to work, which `\W` won't do on its own.

You need to first prep `str`, then create the reversed version of it, and do the check:

```
function palindrome(str) {
    var strReverse;
    str = str.toLowerCase().replace(/\W|_+/g,'');
    strReverse = str.split('').reverse().join('');
    return strReverse === str;
}
```

**Live Example:**

```js
function palindrome(str) {
    var strReverse;
    str = str.toLowerCase().replace(/\W|_+/g,'');
    strReverse = str.split('').reverse().join('');
    return strReverse === str;
}
function test(str, expectedResult) {
    var result = palindrome(str);
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.className = !result == !expectedResult ? "good" : "bad";
    p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(str));
    document.body.appendChild(p);
}
test("eye", true);
test("race car", true);
test("not a palindrome", false);
test("A man, a plan, a canal. Panama", true);
test("never odd or even", true);
test("nope", false);
test("almostomla", false);
test("My age is 0, 0 si ega ym.", true);
test("1 eye for of 1 eye.", false);
test("0_0 (: /-\ :) 0-0", true);
```

```css
.good {
  color: green;
}
.bad {
  color: #d00;
}
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="//tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```